# how to solve the error below to could install GTK on visual studio code in my cs50 development environment?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

Upon writing the following command in my venv environment in visual studio code in cs50 development environment: pip install pygobject, I got the error below. how can I solve it

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pygobject
Downloading PyGObject-3.44.1.tar.gz (720 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 720.5/720.5 kB 19.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pycairo>=1.16.0 (from pygobject)
Downloading pycairo-1.24.0.tar.gz (344 kB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 344.9/344.9 kB 325.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pygobject, pycairo
Building wheel for pygobject (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

```
 `× Building wheel for pygobject (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [73 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/pygtkcompat
      copying pygtkcompat/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/pygtkcompat
      copying pygtkcompat/generictreemodel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/pygtkcompat
      copying pygtkcompat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/pygtkcompat
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi
      copying gi/pygtkcompat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi
      copying gi/_gtktemplate.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi
      copying gi/_error.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi
      copying gi/importer.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi
      copying gi/_signalhelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi
      copying gi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi
      copying gi/_propertyhelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi
      copying gi/_option.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi
      copying gi/_ossighelper.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi
      copying gi/_constants.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi
      copying gi/module.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi
      copying gi/docstring.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi
      copying gi/types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/repository
      copying gi/repository/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/repository
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/Gdk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/Gio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/GIMarshallingTests.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/Pango.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/GdkPixbuf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/Gtk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/keysyms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/GLib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/overrides
      copying gi/overrides/GObject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/overrides
      warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
      
running build_ext
      pycairo: trying include directory: '/tmp/pip-build-env-kaa_3yxz/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cairo/include'
      pycairo: found '/tmp/pip-build-env-kaa_3yxz/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cairo/include/py3cairo.h'
      building 'gi._gi' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi
      clang -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -ferror-limit=1 -gdwarf-4 -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wshadow -fPIC -DPY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb/gi -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/python3.11 -c gi/gimodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/gimodule.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wnull-dereference -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wwrite-strings -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden
      clang -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -ferror-limit=1 -gdwarf-4 -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wshadow -fPIC -DPY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb/gi -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/python3.11 -c gi/pygboxed.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/pygboxed.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wnull-dereference -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wwrite-strings -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden
      clang -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -ferror-limit=1 -gdwarf-4 -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wshadow -fPIC -DPY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb/gi -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/python3.11 -c gi/pygenum.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/pygenum.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wnull-dereference -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wwrite-strings -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden
      clang -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -ferror-limit=1 -gdwarf-4 -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wshadow -fPIC -DPY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb/gi -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/python3.11 -c gi/pygflags.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/pygflags.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wnull-dereference -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wwrite-strings -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden
      clang -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -ferror-limit=1 -gdwarf-4 -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wshadow -fPIC -DPY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb/gi -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/python3.11 -c gi/pygi-argument.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/pygi-argument.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wnull-dereference -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wwrite-strings -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden
      clang -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -ferror-limit=1 -gdwarf-4 -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wshadow -fPIC -DPY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb/gi -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/python3.11 -c gi/pygi-array.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/pygi-array.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wnull-dereference -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wwrite-strings -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden
      clang -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -ferror-limit=1 -gdwarf-4 -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wshadow -fPIC -DPY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb/gi -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/python3.11 -c gi/pygi-basictype.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/pygi-basictype.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wnull-dereference -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wwrite-strings -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden
      clang -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -ferror-limit=1 -gdwarf-4 -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wshadow -fPIC -DPY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb/gi -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/python3.11 -c gi/pygi-boxed.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/pygi-boxed.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wnull-dereference -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wwrite-strings -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden
      clang -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -ferror-limit=1 -gdwarf-4 -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wshadow -fPIC -DPY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb/gi -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/python3.11 -c gi/pygi-cache.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/pygi-cache.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wnull-dereference -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wwrite-strings -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden
      clang -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -ferror-limit=1 -gdwarf-4 -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wshadow -fPIC -DPY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb/gi -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/python3.11 -c gi/pygi-ccallback.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/pygi-ccallback.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wnull-dereference -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wwrite-strings -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden
      clang -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -ferror-limit=1 -gdwarf-4 -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wshadow -fPIC -DPY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb -I/tmp/pip-install-vzy318js/pygobject_50664a6abe9745079ea5bd8f68d82bcb/gi -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/python3.11 -c gi/pygi-closure.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/gi/pygi-closure.o -Wall -Warray-bounds -Wcast-align -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wnull-dereference -Wold-style-definition -Wpacked -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Wunused-but-set-variable -Wwrite-strings -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden
      gi/pygi-closure.c:635:5: error: 'g_callable_info_free_closure' is deprecated: Use 'g_callable_info_destroy_closure' instead [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          g_callable_info_free_closure (invoke_closure->info,
          ^
      /usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0/girffi.h:105:1: note: 'g_callable_info_free_closure' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
      GI_DEPRECATED_IN_1_72_FOR(g_callable_info_destroy_closure)
      ^
      /usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0/giversionmacros.h:186:47: note: expanded from macro 'GI_DEPRECATED_IN_1_72_FOR'
      # define GI_DEPRECATED_IN_1_72_FOR(f)         GI_DEPRECATED_FOR(f)
                                                    ^
      /usr/include/gobject-introspection-1.0/giversionmacros.h:37:31: note: expanded from macro 'GI_DEPRECATED_FOR'
      # define GI_DEPRECATED_FOR(f) G_DEPRECATED_FOR(f) _GI_EXTERN
                                    ^
      /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:1113:44: note: expanded from macro 'G_DEPRECATED_FOR'
      #define G_DEPRECATED_FOR(f) __attribute__((__deprecated__("Use '" #f "' instead")))
                                                 ^
      fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
      2 errors generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pygobject
  Building wheel for pycairo (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for pycairo: filename=pycairo-1.24.0-cp311-cp311-linux_x86_64.whl size=202589 sha256=cf4bb52a50d6784130b3c0da3ed21a1045a3470647254b2697d7f35e0b1b81ff
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-urfc2jco/wheels/14/9b/b2/f69b9ef3e55959c15dee12464e2da91d2f5df92a48b3d5f1f8
Successfully built pycairo
Failed to build pygobject
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pygobject, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```